# Db2 before trigger and writing to a log

Tags: sql, logging, triggers, db2

We have a simple trigger that prevents inserts:

```
db2 "CREATE TRIGGER noins_isrt
NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE ON userid.customer
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '99999' ('Updates not allowed')
"
```

Is there a way to log the content of the update?  For example, they were updating the customer.name or phone number?

Comment: Do you mean in the database log or in your own audit table?  You can easily insert a row with this information in your own audit table.

Comment: It would be in my "own audit table".  Not in the database log.

Comment: . . Then you would just add an `insert` statement into the trigger.  I think of such an insert as much easier than writing a trigger.

Comment: Changed the trigger from before to after and the signal of the sqlstate will rollback the update to the customer table (which is good) but also does not allow the insert into gtmp (the audit table) (which is not good ).

Comment: If you don't want people to update the trigger, why not just `REVOKE` that access?  There are a number of things that can turn triggers off (mostly related to DB maintenance), so this isn't necessarily completely resilient either.  What version of DB2?  Who are you worried about updating this information?  DBAs (able to turn off triggers...)?   Application users (who should only have access through a written program)?

Comment: We are having no problems stopping the update.  Trigger works great !!  However, our goal is to capture the data that the user is updating.  We do not want to revoke access.  Correct - drop trigger <Trigname> can turn off the trigger.  The version of db2 LUW is 9.1 (which is out of support), but we plan on moving many of our instances to 10.X.  Mostly we want to keep rogue tests and developers from making changes to the table.  This is not a concern with our application users.

Comment: Are you using `WITH NC` for your audit `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax for DB2 triggers, but this would be a typical syntax for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER noins_isrt
NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE ON userid.customer
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
begin
    insert into MyAuditTable(value)
        select new.value;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '99999' ('Updates not allowed')
end;
```

Comment: So, the syntax is where the real problem is
Received error unsupported triggered Statement

The code worked on to be:
CREATE TRIGGER noins_isrt
NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE ON userid.customer
REFERENCING NEW AS n OLD as o
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
begin atomic
    insert into gtmp (client_id) values n.ID;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '99999' ;
end

SQL0797N  The trigger "USERID.NOINS_ISRT" is defined with an unsupported triggered SQL statement.  LINE NUMBER=11.  SQLSTATE=42987
However, the triggered SQL statements in a BEFORE trigger
    cannot include: - a nested DELETE, INSERT, MERGE, or UPDATE statement

Comment: sorry formatting is so ugly... limited space on comment...  funny stackoverflow limitation

Comment: I just added a semicolon after `new.value`.  It is possible that would help, because `select new.value signal` is allowed syntax.  I'm surprised DB2 doesn't allow "before" triggers to do inserts into other tables.

Comment: Gordon thank you so much for your responses.  I have added the semicolon and removed the semicolon.  The issue know is that when the trigger hits the sql state - the entire transaction is rolled back.  Both the update that fires the trigger and the insert that writes to the logging table.

Comment: @Justin . . . Ah yes.  This rings a bell (and brings back painful memories).  This is one reason why I always wrap my insert/update/deletes in stored procedures and put the logic there.

Comment: @Justin . . . One solution is to use an `instead of` trigger.  However, you won't be able to signal an error.  When you do the update, you'll have to check the number of rows affected.